Remove Entity from Option Flow
Hello everybody i am currently writing a home assistant integration, where i can monitor my pv devices. i have implemented a option flow (configure button). i can add sensores but i cant remove them. And I really don't know how to solve this. PLease help! Thank you in advance
Sensor.py
enter """The my-PV integration."""

import logging
from homeassistant.const import CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS
from homeassistant.helpers.update_coordinator import CoordinatorEntity
from homeassistant.const import (
UnitOfElectricCurrent,
UnitOfFrequency,
UnitOfTemperature,
)

from .const import SENSOR_TYPES, DOMAIN, DATA_COORDINATOR
from .coordinator import MYPVDataUpdateCoordinator

_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


async def async_setup_entry(hass, entry, async_add_entities):
"""Add an my-PV entry."""
coordinator: MYPVDataUpdateCoordinator = hass.data[DOMAIN][entry.entry_id][
    DATA_COORDINATOR
]

entities = []

if CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS in entry.options:
    for sensor in entry.options[CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS]:
        entities.append(MypvDevice(coordinator, sensor, entry.title))  
else:
    for sensor in entry.data[CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS]:
        entities.append(MypvDevice(coordinator, sensor, entry.title))
async_add_entities(entities)


class MypvDevice(CoordinatorEntity):
"""Representation of a my-PV device."""

def __init__(self, coordinator, sensor_type, name):
    """Initialize the sensor."""
    super().__init__(coordinator)
    self._sensor = SENSOR_TYPES[sensor_type][0]
    self._name = name
    self.type = sensor_type
    self._data_source = SENSOR_TYPES[sensor_type][3]
    self.coordinator = coordinator
    self._last_value = None
    self._unit_of_measurement = SENSOR_TYPES[self.type][1]
    self._icon = SENSOR_TYPES[self.type][2]
    self.serial_number = self.coordinator.data["info"]["sn"]
    self.model = self.coordinator.data["info"]["device"]
    _LOGGER.debug(self.coordinator)

@property
def name(self):
    """Return the name of the sensor."""
    return f"{self._name} {self._sensor}"

@property
def state(self):
    """Return the state of the device."""
    try:
        state = self.coordinator.data[self._data_source][self.type]
        if self.type == "power_act":
            if relOut is not None and loadNom is not None:
                relOut = int(self.coordinator.data[self._data_source]["rel1_out"])
                loadNom = int(self.coordinator.data[self._data_source]["load_nom"])
            state = (relOut * loadNom) + int(state)
        self._last_value = state
    except Exception as ex:
        _LOGGER.error(ex)
        state = self._last_value
    if state is None:
        return state
    if self._unit_of_measurement == UnitOfFrequency.HERTZ:
        return state / 1000
    if self._unit_of_measurement == UnitOfTemperature.CELSIUS:
        return state / 10
    if self._unit_of_measurement == UnitOfElectricCurrent.AMPERE:
        return state / 10
    return state

@property
def unit_of_measurement(self):
    """Return the unit of measurement this sensor expresses itself in."""
    return self._unit_of_measurement

@property
def icon(self):
    """Return icon."""
    return self._icon

@property
def unique_id(self):
    """Return unique id based on device serial and variable."""
    return "{} {}".format(self.serial_number, self._sensor)

@property
def device_info(self):
    """Return information about the device."""
    return {
        "identifiers": {(DOMAIN, self.serial_number)},
        "name": self._name,
        "manufacturer": "my-PV",
        "model": self.model,
    }code here

config_flow.py
import logging
import voluptuous as vol
import ipaddress
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientTimeout

from homeassistant import config_entries
import homeassistant.helpers.config_validation as cv

from homeassistant.const import (
CONF_HOST,
CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS,
)
from homeassistant.core import HomeAssistant, callback

from .const import DOMAIN, SENSOR_TYPES  # pylint:disable=unused-import

_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

DEFAULT_MONITORED_CONDITIONS = [
"temp1"
]

@callback
def mypv_entries(hass: HomeAssistant):
"""Return the hosts for the domain."""
return set(
    (entry.data[CONF_HOST]) for entry in hass.config_entries.async_entries(DOMAIN)
)

class MypvConfigFlow(config_entries.ConfigFlow, domain=DOMAIN):
"""Mypv config flow."""

VERSION = 1
CONNECTION_CLASS = config_entries.CONN_CLASS_LOCAL_POLL

def __init__(self) -> None:
    """Initialize the config flow."""
    self._errors = {}
    self._info = {}
    self._host = None
    self._filtered_sensor_types = {}
    self._devices = {}

def _host_in_configuration_exists(self, host) -> bool:
    """Return True if host exists in configuration."""
    return host in mypv_entries(self.hass)

async def _get_sensor(self, host):
    """Fetch sensor data and update _filtered_sensor_types."""
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        try:
            timeout = ClientTimeout(total=5)
            async with session.get(f"http://{host}/data.jsn", timeout=timeout) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    data = await response.json()
                    json_keys = set(data.keys())
                    self._filtered_sensor_types = {}

                    for key, value in SENSOR_TYPES.items():
                        if key in json_keys:
                            self._filtered_sensor_types[key] = value[0]
                    
                    if not self._filtered_sensor_types:
                        _LOGGER.warning("No matching sensors found on the device.")
                else:
                    self._filtered_sensor_types = {}
                    _LOGGER.error(f"Can't connect to {host}: Bad HTTP Request status")

        except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
            _LOGGER.error(f"Failed to connect to {host}: {e}")
            self._filtered_sensor_types = {}
        except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
            _LOGGER.error(f"Timeout error occured on {host}: {e}")
            self._filtered_sensor_types = {}

async def async_step_user(self, user_input=None):
    """Handle the initial step."""
    return self.async_show_menu(
        step_id="user",
        menu_options={
            "ip_known": "IP address",
            "ip_unknown": "IP subnet scan"
        },
    )  

async def async_step_ip_known(self, user_input=None):
    if user_input is not None:
        self._host = user_input[CONF_HOST]
        if self.is_valid_ip(self._host):
            device = await self.check_ip_device(self._host)
            if device:
                if not self._host_in_configuration_exists(self._host):
                    self._devices[self._host] = f"{device} ({self._host})"
                    await self._get_sensor(self._host)
                    return await self.async_step_sensors()
                else:
                    self._errors[CONF_HOST] = "host_already_configured"
            else:
                self._errors[CONF_HOST] = "could_not_connect"
        else:
            self._errors[CONF_HOST] = "invalid_ip"

    user_input = user_input or {CONF_HOST: "192.168.0.0"}

    ip_known_schema = vol.Schema(
        {vol.Required(CONF_HOST, default="192.168.0.0"): str}
    )
    return self.async_show_form(
        step_id="ip_known",
        data_schema=ip_known_schema,
        errors=self._errors
    )

async def async_step_ip_unknown(self, user_input=None):
    errors = {}
    if user_input is not None:
        subnet = user_input["subnet"]
        if self.is_valid_subnet(subnet):
            self._devices = await self.scan_devices(subnet)
            if self._devices:
                return await self.async_step_select_device()
            else:
                errors["base"] = "no_devices_found"
        else:
            errors["base"] = "invalid_subnet"
        
    ip_unknown_schema = vol.Schema(
        {vol.Required("subnet", default="192.168.0"): str}
    )

    return self.async_show_form(
        step_id="ip_unknown",
        data_schema=ip_unknown_schema,
        errors=errors
    )  

async def async_step_select_device(self, user_input=None):
    if user_input is not None:
        self._host = list(self._devices.keys())[list(self._devices.values()).index(user_input["device"])]
        await self._get_sensor(self._host)
        return await self.async_step_sensors()        
    
    select_device_schema = vol.Schema({
        vol.Required("device"): vol.In(list(self._devices.values()))
    })
    
    return self.async_show_form(
        step_id="select_device",
        data_schema=select_device_schema,
        description_placeholders={"devices": ", ".join(self._devices.values())}
    )  
    
def is_valid_ip(self, ip):
    try:
        ipaddress.ip_address(ip)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        _LOGGER.error("Invalid IP entered")
        return False

def is_valid_subnet(self, subnet):
    cntPeriod = subnet.count('.')
    if cntPeriod != 2:
        _LOGGER.error("Invalid subnet")
        return False
    ip = subnet + ".0"
    return self.is_valid_ip(ip)
    
async def check_ip_device(self, ip):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        return await self.check_device(session, ip)

async def scan_devices(self, subnet):
    devices = {}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for i in range(1, 255):
            ip = f"{subnet}.{i}"
            tasks.append(self.check_device(session, ip))

        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        for ip, device_name in zip([f"{subnet}.{i}" for i in range(1, 255)], results):
            if device_name is not None and not self._host_in_configuration_exists(ip):
                devices[ip] = f"{device_name} ({ip})"

    return devices

async def check_device(self, session, ip):
    try:
        timeout = ClientTimeout(total=15)
        async with session.get(f"http://{ip}/mypv_dev.jsn", timeout=timeout) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                data = await response.json()
                return data.get("device")
            else:
                return None
    except aiohttp.ClientError:
        return None
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return None

async def async_step_sensors(self, user_input=None):
    """Handle the sensor selection step."""
    if user_input is not None:                
        return self.async_create_entry(
            title=f"{self._devices[self._host]}",
            data={
                CONF_HOST: self._host,
                CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS: user_input[CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS],
            },
        )

    setup_schema = vol.Schema(
        {
            vol.Required(
                CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS, default=DEFAULT_MONITORED_CONDITIONS
            ): cv.multi_select(self._filtered_sensor_types),
        }
    )

    return self.async_show_form(
        step_id="sensors", data_schema=setup_schema, errors=self._errors
    )

async def async_step_import(self, user_input=None):
    """Import a config entry."""
    if self._host_in_configuration_exists(user_input[CONF_HOST]):
        return self.async_abort(reason="host_exists")
    self._host = user_input[CONF_HOST]
    if not await self.check_ip_device(self._host):
        return self.async_abort(reason="invalid_ip_address")
    await self._get_sensor(self._host)
    return await self.async_step_sensors(user_input)


@staticmethod
@callback
    def async_get_options_flow(config_entry: config_entries.ConfigEntry) ->         

config_entries.OptionsFlow:
return MypvOptionsFlowHandler(config_entry)
class MypvOptionsFlowHandler(config_entries.OptionsFlow):
"""Handles options flow"""
def __init__(self, config_entry: config_entries.ConfigEntry) -> None:
    """Initialize options flow."""
    self.config_entry = config_entry
    self.filtered_sensor_types = config_entry.data.get('_filtered_sensor_types', {})

async def async_step_init(self, user_input=None):
    """Manage the options."""
    if user_input is not None:
        return self.async_create_entry(
            title="",
            data={
                CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS: user_input[CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS],
            },
        )

    options_schema = vol.Schema(
        {
            vol.Required(
                CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS,
                default=self.config_entry.options.get(
                    CONF_MONITORED_CONDITIONS, DEFAULT_MONITORED_CONDITIONS
                ),
            ): cv.multi_select(self.filtered_sensor_types),
        }
    )

    return self.async_show_form(step_id="init", data_schema=options_schema)

